# Calculating voltage drop across part of an AC circuit

Tags: ac, waveform

I have the question:

"If the supply to a circuit is \$25\sin (628.3 t) ~V\$ and the voltage drop across one of the components is \$18\sin (628.3t - 0.52) ~V\$. Calculate the voltage drop across the remainder of the circuit."

I have never come across a question like this before. The questions I am use to involve using the cosine and sine rule to derive an expression. However, this method does not work for this question.

I am not quite sure how I would solve this question. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

The solutions says that the answer should be \$12.96 \sin(628.3t + 0.762)~V\$ but I have no idea what method to use to get this answer.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  Do you understand what the "- 0.52" in the second sine expression tells you?  That is crucial in understanding the problem.

Comment: I am not asking you to do my homework for me. The final answer I have stated I am just asking for any hints in order to solve the question such as method which I need to use for example sine rule etc. And yes that is the phase shift :)

Comment: Good that you understand that it's a phase shift.  That is important.  However, you're asking about the whole problem, not specifically where you're stuck.  We don't do that here.   Go look up something called a *phasor*.

Comment: [METHODS OF ADDING ALTERNATING
WAVEFORMS](http://documents.routledge-interactive.s3.amazonaws.com/9780415662840/answers/UEM_Sol_to_Exerc_Chap_050.pdf) is a good place to start.  Put your progress here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a picture would help you see what you have to do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) yes that has helped me understand the question better.